# Half LCD monitor is bluish

Tags: display, troubleshooting, lcd

Asus LCD monitor in question shows image that is split vertically exactly in two halves. The left half is normal, while the right half has strong bluish tint. This is the case also when just booting Windows (e.g. black screen in pre-boot sequence appears blue).

I assume that on the right half all blue components of RGB triplet operate at top intensity at all times, for some reason. I don't know why. All cords are securely connected. Monitor used to start working normally for some time , then reverted back to the problem and has stayed that way since.

What could be causing this problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to connect it to a different PC?

Comment: Yes. Same problem. Both on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Then I guess you should take it to a service center. Definitely some hardware issue.